# Is static_assert compiled into the binary file

Tags: c++, compilation, static-assert

I'd like to use `static_assert` in my C++11 project to do some compile time check.

As my understanding, `static_assert` won't be executed at runtime, right?

If so, when I compile my project by executing the command about compilation, such as `gcc ...`, the compiler will build the `static_assert` into the binary file or the `static_assert` will be totally ignored, just like a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is static_assert compiled into the binary file

No.

> As my understanding, static_assert won't be executed at runtime, right?

Right.

> the compiler will build the static_assert into the binary file

No.

> the static_assert will be totally ignored, just like a comment?

No, it's not a comment - the expression is checked, and if the expression is false, then a message is shown. When the expression is not a constant (can't be computed at compile time) then also a message is shown.

Comment: My bad. Let me make it clearer. If the expression of `static_assert` is true, so the compilation will succeed. In this case, `static_assert` is just like a comment because it will be ignored by the compiler. Right?

Comment: `In this case, static_assert is just like a comment because it will be ignored by the compiler. Right?` yes.

Comment: @Yves not quite. Code typically isnt compiled only once. If you make assumptions explicit in code then a `static_assert( some_compile_time_constant != 0)` will fire when code is refactored and the assumption no longer holds while a comment `// this is never 0` is easily overlooked

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the old `assert()`, which is a runtime test, the `static_assert` is tested by the compiler and results in a compile time error if not satisfied. Or if it cannot be tested statically...

Then, at  runtime, it is already known to be true and does not need to be tested again.